# Regex match between parenthesis stopping at first space within parenthesis

Tags: regex

I have a string like `some data (920 seconds)` and want to extract only `920`.

So far I have `\([^)]*\)` to extract all text between the parenthesis.  It returns `(920 seconds)`

How can I exclude the parenthesis & extract anything after `(` stopping at the first whitespace?

EDIT: `920` is a string and not an integer due to how the data is formatted

Comment: Use: `\(([^\s)]*)[^)]*\)` and get text from capture group #1

Answer (score 2):

You can use a capture group to get your substring:

```
\(([^\s)]*)[^)]*\)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wKlaYQ/1)

Answer (score 1):

Here, we can simply use <kbd>(</kbd> as a left boundary and collect the desired digits:

```
(.*?\()[0-9]+(.*)
```

We can add a capturing group around numbers and store it in `$2`:

```
(.*?\()([0-9]+)(.*)
```

[image]

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Hp79OL/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### JavaScript Demo

```js
const regex = /(.*?\()([0-9]+)(.*)/gm;
const str = `some data (920 seconds)
Any other data(10101 minutes)
Any other data(8918 hours)`;
const subst = `$2`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### Python Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(.*?\()([0-9]+)(.*)"

test_str = ("some data (920 seconds)\n"
    "Any other data(10101 minutes)\n"
    "Any other data(8918 hours)")

subst = "\\2"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```